# Dominated Convergence for the upper Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, outer-measure

In 2.4.2 of **Geometric Measure Theory**, Federer gives the following description of the upper (Lebesgue) integral. Given a (not necessarily measurable) function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, we call $u : X \to \mathbb{R}$ an *upper function* of $f$ if $f \leq u$ almost everywhere and $u$ is a measurable function with countable range. We then define the *upper integral* of $f$ to be the infimum
$$\int^* f \mathrm{d} \mu : = \inf \left\{ \int u \mathrm{d} \mu : \textrm{$u$ is an upper function for $f$} \right\} .$$
Lower functions and lower integrals are then defined analogously. Federer then says that a function is *integrable* if it's measurable and its upper and lower integrals agree, and proceeds with actual measure theory.

My question is this. Do the classical integral convergence theorems like Monotone Convergence and Dominated Convergence hold for the upper integral? If not, is there an easy counterexample? And is there anywhere I can read more about these upper integrals?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit of a sidetrack, but the definition of "integrable" you've mentioned here is different from its usual sense.  Does Federer allow the lower integral to be $\infty$ and still call the function "integrable"?

Comment: To answer my own question, it looks like Federer's "integrable" means that the integral exists in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.  In contrast, Federer uses "summable" to mean the integral exists in $\mathbb{R}$ (which is what many people call "integrable").  Do note that he effectively specialized $u$ to be "an integrable function with countable range", not just a measurable function (it makes sense as "integrable functions with countable range" can be defined without reference to upper and lower integrals)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, he uses a slightly different terminology. I think the common terminology is to use integrable to mean having a finite integral, which is what I used here. I mentioned Federer but didn't expect the reader to have a copy in front of them, hence I summarized the relevant parts.